# Unable to create a custom domain using Firebase Hosting API

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-hosting

I'm trying to automate custom domain creation process in Firebase Hosting, I am using Go library, but it doesn't work, I am also happy to know about plain REST alternative. I always get this error:

> googleapi: Error 400: Domain `test1.example.com` not associated with
> project, failedPrecondition exit status 1

```
firebase, _ := firebasehosting.NewService(context.Background())

domain := &firebasehosting.Domain{
    DomainName: "test1.example.com",
    Site:       "dashboard-v1-staging",
}

createCall := firebase.Projects.Sites.Domains.Create("projects/ID/sites/ID", domain)
_, err = createCall.Do()
if err != nil && !googleapi.IsNotModified(err) {
    log.Println(err)
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

Comment: *firebaser here* Hey Alex. Kudos on finding this API, as it's not actually finished yet (documentation is forthcoming).  I am checking with the engineering team to see what might be going wrong, and will post an answer when I know more.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that API can't do that yet, and Firebase team is working on that. It was confirmed in the ticket I submitted on Github - https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/issues/1798